# how Mark Checkboxes after create a dynamic form in PHP using JQuery,

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check some checkboxes based on it value.
In my code, I can update the database using this ckbxs, but when I try load the updated date, the status is showed as uncheck.
So, I am trying to read the html, after create the form, to check the values and then check the ckbx. 
What can I do here to fix it? 
Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
       if (this.value == 1) {
            (function(){this.attr('checked', true);})
        }
    } )
})
```

Comment: Not every version of jQuery supports the attribute selector correctly when the value of the attribute is unquoted. YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Willian, now I am using a onChange and I got what I need...

```
function changerCB(idCheck){

$(document).ready(function() {
$.post('ajaxUpdate.php', {
    id: document.getElementById(idCheck).id,
    value: document.getElementById(idCheck).checked?1:0
    }, function(data){
        $('#display').html(data.returnValue)
        if(data.success) {              
    } else {
    }
}, 'json');
return false;  
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the `this`s in a `$( )` and change `value` to `val()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
       if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can add an onchange event to each checkbox and set the value based on whether it is checked or not

Comment: its work fine, but know i have a new problem. could you revise please ? Is not possible to set the value as 0. It is always returning 1.
 ` $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
   $.post('update.php', {
    id: this.id,
    value: $(this).attr("checked")?1:0
    }, function(data){
     $('#display').html(data.returnValue)
     if(data.success) {    
    } else {
    }
   }, 'json');
  return false;  
  });
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
  }
  });
        });`

Comment: Attributes are string values, so testing for a not-empty string will always return true whether the value is "true" or "false". Try changing    $(this).attr("checked")?1:0  to   $(this).attr("checked")=="true"?1:0

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"][value="1"]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```